# AG-Grid: Is it possible to move the status bar / status panel to the top of the grid, between the header & rows?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We have a requirement to display a custom Angular component at the top of the grid, between the header rows and data rows, similar to a [Pinned Row](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/), but with our own custom content that spans all the columns.

The [Status Bar Panel](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-status-bar-component/) looks very similar to what we need, but the examples only show it rendered at the bottom of the grid. I was wondering if there was a way we could make it render at the top. Are there any alternatives?

The example renders like this:
[image: Status Bar Bottom]

We want to acheive something like this:
[image: Status Bar Top]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by CSS trick.

Have a look at this plunk: [Status Bar Panel - at top](https://plnkr.co/edit/XsRV73Ze6fIBklUq)

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-status-bar {
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 5px;
  border-top: none !important;
}
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-body-viewport {
  top: 50px;
  border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
}
```